# Is ReactDOM.findDOMNode required in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've taken next code from here: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/adding-user-accounts.
Can I replace in this particular case
`ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.container))` with
 `this.refs.container`
without any hidden bugs in future?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Blaze } from 'meteor/blaze';

export default class AccountsUIWrapper extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Use Meteor Blaze to render login buttons
    this.view = Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons,
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.container));
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Clean up Blaze view
    Blaze.remove(this.view);
  }
  render() {
    // Just render a placeholder container that will be filled in
    return <span ref="container" />;
  }
}
```

Or maybe even change using callback function:

```
....
export default class AccountsUIWrapper extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Use Meteor Blaze to render login buttons
    this.view = Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons,
      this.container);
  }
  ....
  render() {
    // Just render a placeholder container that will be filled in
    return <span ref={(node) => (this.container = node) />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the react refs documentation

> If you worked with React before, you might be familiar with an older
>   API where the ref attribute is a string, like "textInput", and the DOM
>   node is accessed as this.refs.textInput. We advise against it because
>   string refs have some issues, are considered legacy, and are likely to
>   be removed in one of the future releases. If you're currently using
>   this.refs.textInput to access refs, we recommend the callback pattern
>   instead.

Hence `ref callback` is the right way to go if you want to have future support

```
export default class AccountsUIWrapper extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {

    this.view = Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons,
      this.container);
  }
  ....
  render() {

    return <span ref={(node) => (this.container = node) />;
  }
}
```

Comment: What about *ReactDOM.findDOMNode*? Is it safe to omit it in this case?

Comment: Yes surely since you are still using the string refs. Ref callback is the best and the suggested way to go